# Get all records which have no has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have products that i can get by

```
products = restaurant.products
```

now get products which not belong to ess (ess is an enum here) and also which have nil values.

```
products = products.where('external_product_source != ? OR external_product_source IS NULL', 0)
```

in my spree_product.rb i have following associations

```
has_one :spree_product_set, class_name: 'Spree::ProductSet', as: :source, dependent: :destroy
has_one :snacks_case, -> { snacks_case }, class_name: 'Spree::ProductSet', as: :source, dependent: :destroy
```

and in my spree_product_set.rb i have

```
belongs_to :source, polymorphic: true
```

now I want to get those products from my collection that have not a single snacks_case

Comment: You need to perform a LEFT_JOIN and COUNT the number of associated records. You obviously want records where the count is 0.

Comment: See left_outer_joins https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/left_outer_joins